# Using React components from npm in Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I would like to know how to use React components from npm in Meteor 1.3 using `import`.

I am trying to use [react-gravatar](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-gravatar) in my project. I did `npm install --save react-gravatar`. And in my component, I required it:

```
import React from 'react';
import Gravatar from 'react-gravatar';

export default React.createClass({

  render() {
    ...
  }
});
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'querystring'
```

I think this is because `querystring` is not available in client side, and I need to use browserify-reactify of some sort. But how can I do so in Meteor 1.3?

Comment: Looking at the dependency graph for the current version of `react-gravatar` I can't see querystring. Are you sure the problem is not with something else?

Comment: I think `querystring` is a native node.js module. I can confirm this component works when used in a plain node project with gulp and reactify.